# Excel inadvertently adding rows to a workbook

Tags: excel

At work we have a workbook that has 3-5 tables, each table being on each new page of a particular sheet (the "1st" row of each page, same sheet). The tables don't extend past their particular page but for some reason, tables on the 2nd page or beyond will randomly appear somewhere on the bottom of the previous page or below the starting line of the page.

I have tried to test it and we do not insert or delete rows and the rows are not resized, either. I tried to add a page break but if it's added after the table, the table ends at that spot on the page (not what we want). If the page break is added at the start of the table (top row of the page), this causes the prior page to be continued to the next page with a lot of blank space then the table moved to another page (ex - Table 3 on page 3 might be moved to page 5 with Table 2 (from page 2) ranging from pages 2-3.5 (essentially 3rd sheet but halfway)and Table 3 on page 4.

How can I have these tables each stick to one page each unless the table clearly requires all rows/space within that page range?

You can see in the first pic that the table resides at row 2 as designed. The next picture, however, has the graph starting in row 55 instead of 57 (each table should be at the top of the sheet). Same for the third pic, should start on row 114 in this case but it's starting at 109. When the tables are created, they're created at the top of each sheet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a picture of what you're seeing so we can figure out what's wrong? Your explanation is a little confusing. Also, do you have any code for this?

Comment: Sorry I got wrapped on with other work and thought I was going to have to upload pictures to a site somewhere so I'm glad adding images was easier than I imagined. There is no code for the sheet or any macros that run on it. I do name each table as well as the second to last column but I don't know why naming conventions would cause the issue.