# #REF! error on one cell but not others

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that serves as the master book and pulls information from two other books. I have a macro run at opening that opens the other two workbooks then closes them to ensure it updates all info. (The data used to pull on its own but stopped the other day so I created a macro to open the books which got me the updated data.) All the formulas pull up correctly except for one. All the formulas are similar except for the names of the table which I ensured my table was named appropriately. Any idea why the following formula would cause a #REF! error when other formulas point to that same sheet without issue?

=ROUNDUP(SUM('M:\Sales\Supervisor\2017 SVR AND MARGIN REPORT BY TEAM\TMR 2017 - Team ABC''s.xlsm'!EscoFebruary2018[Length of Stay])/30,0)

So I noticed that when I change the order of which team is opened by the master, I got more #ref! errors. This time, it's all on one particular team (Dealers). The set up of how these are displayed is: O2:O4,O12 (O12 being the org culprit only) are team ABCs, O6:O10,O13 are team are team Dealers. So I'm thinking the ABCs file opens first, plugs in O2:O4 and O12 then when Dealers opens, it plugs in O6:O10 and maybe when it then tries to fill in O13, it causes the error with O12 because it's not part of the Dealers? I don't know why this would cause issue so any help around it would be appriecated. And no, I cannot move the teams around. O12 and O13 are supervisor positions that the boss wants under the teams and totals (O5,O11 being the totals). Here's an image of the master for better visualization: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14r0tia2xsz2xTp_LXrP-C9fbEQCsRnsz

Comment: When you right-click and delete a column or row, Excel tries to adjust all formulas to account for the change.  If it cannot, then a formula will include `#REF` in the formula that could not be updated.  The cell will also show `#REF`.  Did you right-click and delete a row or column somewhere?

Comment: @JamesL. The sum is performed on a table so I'm not sure why deleting rows would be an issue. I mentioned an issue in this old post I had with no responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601185/excel-inadvertently-adding-rows-to-a-workbook
So I delete rows from the top of a sheet if the sheet randomly gets rows added, pushing the table down some. I have included a link to a piece of the sheet the data is pulled from.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=14LE5k7rKNU2SIdykP4fNZu_HtJn6xIgu
I wouldn't think the removal of rows outside of the tables would cause this.

Comment: I have never used `tables` like that inside of Excel and don't use references to other spreadsheets all that often.  So I'm not sure what is causing your `#REF` issue.  It might help if you add a working formula that references another workbook to your post as a comparison of a formula that works vs one that does not work.

Comment: @JamesL. The problem is the formulas are exactly the same minus the file name (depending on the team) and the names of the employees but here's one example of one that works:
=ROUNDUP(SUM('M:\Sales\Supervisor\2017 SVR AND MARGIN REPORT BY TEAM\TMR 2017 - Team ABC''s.xlsm'!MarkFebruary2018[Length of Stay])/30,0)

Comment: Well, looking at the XLS on your Google Drive, the tables in Excel for Esco, John, Mark, and Suzi are not created the same.  Esco is unique, while the others are all the same.  If I open your spreadsheet and create a formula in any blank (non-table) cell, and type `=`, then click in any of Esco's fields, it uses the table + column notation.  If I do the same for any other user, it simply uses `=J37` (row/column) notation.  So Excel is treating Esco's table differently than everyone else's.  Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: @JamesL. Interesting find! The tables all seem similar. I'll see what I can figure out and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't understand what caused the issue, the workaround to resolve it was to house my aforementioned formulas in the two sub files in each respective workbook then use an index formula to pull the data into the master. I'm guessing the issue has something to do with pulling the value then trying to calculate. Now that it calculates then pulls the data, all is well. Thanks for the help James.